# Calculate $\prod\limits_{n=2}^\infty (1-q^n)$ for $0\leqslant q < 1$, or prove that $\prod\limits_{n=2}^\infty (1-q^n)>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> How to calculate $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-q^n)$$ for $0\leqslant q < 1$?

I tried to apply $\ln$, giving this: $$\sum_{n\geqslant 2} \ln(1-q^n)$$ but I don't know how to calculate either.

Also, is it possible to show that $\prod\limits_{n=2}^\infty (1-q^n)$ is positive, without using known results about $q$-Pochhammer symbols?

Comment: No closed form in terms of usual functions.

Comment: Your product is closely related to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html. You should get a closed for in Theta functions.
For numerical methods see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294697/61216

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this is too high level for me, so I change my initial question a little bit.

Comment: *Hint.* If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1 - a_n)$ converges absolutely as well. Can you show why?

Comment: Yeah of course! If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely, then $a_n \rightarrow 0$ so $|\log(1-a_n)| \sim |a_n|$. But how can I prove that it converges to $l>0$ using this?

Comment: You know that the sum of logarithms of some numbers exists. What does it tell you about the product of the numbers

Comment: That it converges too, doesn't it? But, giving that, I don't know how to show that $0<\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-q^n)$.

Comment: This is more-or-less the Dedekind eta function. If $0\le q<1$ then all terms are positive, so it either converges to a positive number or diverges to zero. But taking logarithms easily implies it does not diverge to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. first show that $\log (1-t) + \frac{t}{1-t}\geq 0$ for $t<1$ (minimum for $t=0$) so that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2} \log(1-q^n) \geq -\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{q^n}{1-q^n} \geq -\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{q^n}{1-q}= -\frac{q^2}{(1-q)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you. This solution is the easiest one, that's why I accepted it.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

For a completely elementary (and quantitative) solution to the answerable part of the question, note that, by convexity of the exponential, for every $x$ in $[0,q]$, $$1-x\geqslant c(q)^x$$ where $c(q)$ solves $$1-q=c(q)^q$$ Using this for $x=q^n\leqslant q$, for every $n\geqslant1$, one gets $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)\geqslant c(q)^{q+q^2+q^3+\cdots}=c(q)^{q/(1-q)}=(1-q)^{1/(1-q)}>0$$ Likewise, $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty(1-q^n)\geqslant (1-q)^{q/(1-q)}>0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really understand what is $c$. I'm not used to that kind of method, to be honest. Could you explain me, please?

Comment: For every $q$, $$c(q)=(1-q)^{1/q}$$ for example, $$c(.5)=.25$$